# How to save and append comment form without refresh the page in drupal 7

Tags: comments

I have a form with comments but this page have counter to cout views of this page.

but every time when comment added on this page that page loaded and my counts increasing 
  after comment added.

but i want to count views when page load first time not by comments module  in drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the [AJAX Comments](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module:

> Provides ajax comments to Drupal sites. Features:
>
> - Makes AJAX submits
> - Allows replies to comments on the actual thread page
> - AJAX comments deleting
> - Works with CAPTCHA
> - Cool jQuery sliding
> - views integration

It will allow users to submit comments without a page refresh, bypassing the extra view count.